# colors are washed out

Tags: 18.04, graphics, colors

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a new desktop with a new screen and the colors seemed bleached (or washed out). This is more obvious with shades of gray that turn into white (e.g., read emails in gmail). Approaches I've already tried:

(1) Running

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"
```

as recommended in previous posts. Doesn't help in my case.

(2) Playing with the resolution under Settings->Displays. Doesn't solve the problem.

(3) The problem is resolved if I change the color profile of my screen in Settings->Devices->Color from the default one to Test Profile Blue or to D50 or D55. However, then the screen becomes blue-ish (with the former profile) or pink-ish (with the latter ones), so it's not a sustainable solution.

Any ideas?

My system's info:

- Ubuntu version: 18.04
- Screen model: Samsung S27F350
- Graphics card vendor: Intel Corporation